# Adding Customer Data in Elasticsearch

Tags: magento2, customer, search, elasticsearch

I want to Add All my customers Data in Elasticsearch Like Products and Category
i want to where should i start and how i can map data

Thank you

Comment: did u get any solutions on this ??

Comment: yead we did some complex coding from basic to aciveve our goal

Comment: could you please help me out on this? Thanks in advance and it's a really needed functionality please help me out.

Comment: Is there any working solution there? I took help from this https://github.com/Overdose-Digital/Elastic. But still i am facing problem to add fields and data in my custom index.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have no clue what's the end purpose of this feature, I can fairly say that this involves some heavy development to address the following high-level key concepts:

1. Creating a new Magento indexer to push the data to Elasticsearch;
2. Create a new index in Elasticsearch to hold the data;
3. Addressing the partial indexation maybe? or just a simple data push to ES when a new customer gets created/ updated/ deleted.
4. Learn about [Elasticsearch document mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html);
5. Link the above mentioned steps so that you collect Magento data and push it to ES on the document structure;
6. (optional?) Not sure where you will consume the indexed data once it gets in Elasticsearch, so that's also another thing to address as you will have to understand the [analysis mechanism and concepts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html).

I would probably start by debugging the default Magento search module to see how it works, maybe it will provide you with details of what you need.

Wish you best of luck!

Comment: thanks for info i am looking into it if you found any futher explanation please share with me